# Continuous functions with convex level sets

Tags: real-analysis, convexity, convex-analysis

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ is  a  continuous  function such that each level set $f^{-1}(c)$ is  a  convex set.
To what extent such functions are studied?

In particular:

1. Is there a partial or  total ordering on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that all functions with this  property, must be monotone?

2.Is it true to say that $f$ is  differentiable, almost every where?

These two questions are motivated by the fact that this property for  continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is  equivalent to monoton property  and every monoton function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is almost every where differentiable.

**Note:** As  usual,  a  convex set in the plane is  a  subset $C$ such that $\forall a,b\in C$  and $\forall t\in [0,1]$  we  have $ta+(1-t)b\in C$

Comment: What do you mean by convex?

Comment: I think a positive answer to (2) would follow from the statement: "If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is such that every set of the form $\{x: (x, y)\in A\}$ or $\{y: (x, y)\in A\}$ has measure 0, then $A$ has measure 0." However, I'm also fairly certain that statement is false.

Comment: @DenisSerre, only for continuous $\phi$; and such $\phi$ are differentiable a.e. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev  the usual convexity as in the plane geometry.

Comment: @DenisSerre I think this is  a classic theorem that an increasing function is  almost every  where differentiable  and we have $\int_{a}^{b}f'\leq f(b)-f(a)$. I learned it from Royden book

Comment: Also function of finite variation $\ f:(a;b)\rightarrow\mathbb R\ $ are differentiable a.e.--they are the differences of two non-decreasing functions (is the *finite variation* a correct term? :-)

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński It is usually called "bounded variation" as far as I know.

Comment: @DenisSerre but you also have the assumption that $\phi$ is increasing - isn't it the case that any increasing continuous function is differentiable a.e.?

Comment: @JohannesHahn -- thank you, it's a relief for me. I could feel that my (:-) term was a bit off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's call the functions defined by Ali Taghavi to be sliced functions: a continuous function $\ f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R\ $ is called *sliced* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \ \forall_{c\in\mathbb R}\ f^{-1}(c)\ $ is convex.

> **NOTATION**: 
>   $$\ [x;y]\ :=\ \{(1\!-\!t)\cdot x\ +\ t\cdot y\ :\ 0\le t\le 1\}\ $$
>   for arbitrary $\ x\ y\in \mathbb R^n\ $ and $\ n=0\ 1\ 2\ \ldots.\ $ Thus $\ [x;y]=[y;x]\ $ in every dimension including $\ n=1$.

**THEOREM 0**   Let $\ f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R\ $ be sliced. Then $\ f^{-1}(C)\ $ is convex for every convex $\ C\subseteq\mathbb R$.

**PROOF**   Let $\ C\subseteq \mathbb R\ $ be convex. Let $\ a\ b\in C.\ $ We want to show that

$$\ [a;b]\ \subseteq\ C $$

If $\ f(a)=f(b)\ $ then the above holds due to the convex part of the definition of a sliced function.

Now, assume $\ f(a)\ne f(b).\ $ Then $\ f^{-1}([f(a);f(b)])\ \cap\ [a;b]\ $ is a closed subset of $\ [a;b].\ $ Next, consider arbitrary $\ x\ y \in [a;b]\cap f^{-1}([f(a);f(b)],\ $ and $\ x\ne y.\ $ If $\ f(x)=f(y)\ $ then again

$$ [x;y]\ \subseteq f^{-1}(x)\ \subseteq\ f^{-1}([f(a);f(b)])  $$

And if $\ f(x)\ne f(y)\ $ then, due to continuity of $\ f\ $ (and of the nature of $\ \mathbb R$) we have

$$ f([x;y])\ \supseteq\ [f(x);f(y)] $$

Thus there exists $\ w\in[x;y]\ $ such that

$$ f(w)\ =\ \frac {f(x)+f(y)}2 $$

We see that $\ w\in(x;y)\ $ belongs to the interior of the interval, and $\ w\in f^{-1}[f(a);f(b)].\ $ This shows that $[a;b]\cap f^{-1}([f(a);f(b)])\ $ is dense in $\ [a;b],\ $ hence $\ [a;b]\subset f^{-1}(C).\ $ **END of PROOF**

> After this exercise we get:

**THEOREM 1**    Let $\ f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R\ $ be sliced. Then there exists $\ (a\ b)\in\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0\ 0)\}\ $ such that:

$$\forall_{(x\ y)\,\ (x'\ y')\,\in\,\mathbb R^2 }\ \ \left(\ a\cdot x+b\cdot y = a\cdot x'+b\cdot y'\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ f(x\ y)=f(x'\ y')\ \right)$$

**PROOF**   The case of a constant function is trivial. Otherwise there exists $\ h\in\mathbb R\ $ such that both sets $\ f^{-1}((-\infty\;h))\ $ and $\ f^{-1}((h;\infty))\ $ are non-empty. Then these two sets are disjoint open half-planes, i.e. they are non-empty, open and convex, and the complement of each of them is non-empty, closed and convex. Thus there exist $\ s\ t\in\mathbb R\ $ and $\ (a\ b)\in\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0\ 0\}\ $ such  that $\ s<t\ $ and

$$f(x\ y) = h\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad s\ \le\ a\cdot x+b\cdot y\ \le\ t$$

Then this $\ (a\ b)\ $ is the one required by the theorem. **END of PROOF**

> This is about all about the general structure of the sliced functions.

A sliced function is constant in the direction perpendicular to the vector $\ (a\ b)\in\mathbb R\setminus\{(0\ 0)\}\ $ (see above), and it is monotone along that direction: let $\ \phi:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R\ $ be given by:

$$\forall_{u\in\mathbb R}\ \ \phi(u)\ :=\ f\left(u\cdot(a\ b)\right)$$

Then $\ \phi\ $ is monotonne. Thus each slide function is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: thanks for the answer. could  you please more explain on the last part of your  proof: what is $\phi$  and  how is your  final  conclusion?

Comment: Are you using some type of geometric Han Banach theorem? could you please more explain?

Comment: I'll add some explanations. This is all elementary. In this finite-dimensional problem there is no need for Hahn-Banach, it's be an overkill. However, this results actually work for any locally convex topologically linear space--your assumption is that strong.

Comment: I think you mean $\phi(u)=f(u.(a,b))$

Comment: Thank you, Ali, indeed. I fixed this typo. Do you still want me to go into details of the proofs? E.g. *Theorem 0* holds for arbitrary real linear spaces (no topology needed). And the bulk of the rest results (but for more detiled moments) hold for arbitrary locally convex topological spaces.

Comment: thank you again for your very interesting answer.  I understand all  details.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your question and for selecting my answer.

Comment: @Holsztyński    Prof. Holsztynski  May I have your email address?Can I ask you to send me an empty message to "alitghv@yahoo.com"? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*Re: Alex' comment on the OP, I assume "convex" w/r/t subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is meant in the usual sense.*

---

Call a function as in the OP *tame*. Here's an answer to (1):

First, I claim there is no total order $\prec$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that any tame function is monotone with respect to $\prec$. To see this, consider the four points $a=(0, 1)$, $b=(1, 0)$, $c=(0, -1)$, and $d=(-1, 0)$. Then we must have:

- Either every point on $l_1$ is $\prec$ every point on $l_2$ ("$l_1\prec l_2$"), or vice versa, and
- Either every point on $l_3$ is $\prec$ every point on $l_4$ ("$l_3\prec l_4$"), or vice versa.

(To see this, consider the tame functions $f(x, y)=x+y$ and $g(x, y)=x-y$.) But now we reach a contradiction: suppose WLOG $l_1\prec l_2$ and $l_3\prec l_4$ - then $c\prec a$ since $l_1\prec l_2$, but $a\prec c$ since $l_3\prec l_4$.

As for partial orders, every function whatsoever is monotone w/r/t the discrete order; so maybe some constraint on the considered partial orders should be imposed?

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure that no partial order with all antichains countable ("c.c.c") can have the desired property; I thought I saw the proof a minute ago, but now I can't quite put it together.

Comment: I deleted a silly response to question (2) - I missed the "almost everywhere" bit.

Comment: thanks  for your elegance argument for non existence of total order.

Comment: I thank you again for your very interesting idea. I am sorry that I can not accept two answer http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-i-can-not-accept-two-answers-on-the-same-my-question-simultaneously

Comment: I can not resist to express my admiration again to your interesting idea.